# How can I use a list to create a table in html?

Tags: html

I am writing a django app with bootstrap and I have a table with a head in one of my pages like the one below:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered table-fixed table">
    <thead class="thead-inverse table_head">
        <tr class="table_head_row">
            <th class="table_head_item">header 1</th>
            <th class="table_head_item">header 2</th>
            <th class="table_head_item">header 3</th>
            <th class="table_head_item">header 4</th>
            <th class="table_head_item">header 5</th>
            <th class="table_head_item">header 6</th>
            <th class="table_head_item">header 7</th>
            <th class="table_head_item">header 8</th>
            <th class="table_head_item">header 9</th>
            <th class="table_head_item">header 10</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

In the above example each header has its own line of code, 10 headers, 10 lines. There is a lot of repetition. I am looking for a way using HTML and not django, to not type almost the same line of code every time.

Using django I could pass the list with the headers from the page's view, like so:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered table-fixed table">
    <thead class="thead-inverse table_head">
        <tr class="table_head_row">
        {% for header in table_headers %}
            <th class="table_head_item">header</th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Below is a mock up in HTML of what it could be like:

```
table_headers = ["header_1", "header_2", ....]
<table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered table-fixed table">
    <thead class="thead-inverse table_head">
        <tr class="table_head_row">
        for header in table_headers
            <th class="table_head_item">header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Can I do something like this just in html and in django ?

Comment: Is this a django form? If so, I have an answer, if not, please post your views.py

Comment: yes you can do that if you are rendering the template and use {{header}} to to get the value in th tag

Comment: @Walucas It is a simple table that is filled with data from a view. Although, the view is not necessary. It's more finding a way to not repeat code.

Comment: take a look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Would you care to explain further ?

Comment: here best explanations from django documentations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Yes, you can use a for loop in a Django template, just like you have done.

Comment: If you post the view we can better understand how to provide an answer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can I use a for loop in a django template and set the loop's list inside the html and not from django ?

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Yes, you can define a list in your view or a custom tag, and then use it in your template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Would you mind giving an example of what you are refering to ?